# How to list Spring Security authorities needed to access Spring Boot endpoints?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application secured by Spring Security. For securing access to particular endpoints we are using `@PreAuthorize` annotation, like `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('first_role','second_role','third_role')")`.

I'm wondering if there is any possibility to generate (statically or dynamically) list of mappings between endpoints and authorities to see which endpoint is secured by what authorities.

So as an output I would like to have something like that:

```
first_role -> endpoint_A, endpoint_B, endpoint_C
second_role -> endpoint_B
third_role -> endpoint_A, endpoint_C
```

or at least:

```
endpoint_A -> first_role, third_role
endpoint_B -> first_role, second_role
endpoint_C -> first_role, third_role
```

Do you know any solution?

Comment: AFAIK there is no build-in way, but you could write it by yourself. You have to go over all your classes/methods and look into the annotations. To make it easier, change `@PreAuthorize` with `@Secured`, it allows only authorities, no SPEL.

Comment: I also need the same sort of solution for my problem: I have a gateway and in my ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter class, I added all my endpoints' antMatchers with the needed role(s) and I want to know which endpoint secured by which role(s), I wanna have a service that can give that to me then I'll show those useful information on my swagger document.

Answer (score 0):

You can secure your endpoints in the configuration class and drop the @PreAuthorize annotation. I suggest that you read this spring documentation about [security expressions](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions). You can user antmatchers to secure a URL for certain group of authorities, roles etc.